# Syntax error if there is a space in JSON object. How to escape space.?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, space

Have a JSON as shown below

```
callback({
    "response":{
       "docs":[
              {
               "A":"qwe",
               "B":"asd",
               "C":"zxc",
               "D":"mnb",
              }]
       "Mapped Site":[
              "qaw",123,
              "asd",123,
              "qwe",123
              ]
       },
      })
```

I am trying to read  JSON data using Jquery ajax api as below

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://qqq.com/",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (msg) {
                         sourcearr = $(msg.response.Mapped Site);
            sourcearr = $.map(sourcearr, function (el) { return el; });
            alert(sourcearr);
            }
         });
```

This throws me syntax error in firebug as there is a space in `Mapped Site`

How can I escape and read the data?

Comment: I think this would help - `msg.response["Mapped Site"]`

Comment: @user1354678... Bulls eye...!!! Thanks a ton it worked.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access json keys like fetching from array if it have spaces.

```
msg.response["Mapped Site"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use bracket notation** to access keys with spaces
like

```
msg.response["Mapped Site"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your json is not formatted correctly. This is right version

```
callback({
"response":{
   "docs":[
          {
           "A":"qwe",
           "B":"asd",
           "C":"zxc",
           "D":"mnb"
          }],
   "Mapped Site":[
          "qaw",123,
          "asd",123,
          "qwe",123
          ]
   }
  })
```

I change this `"D":"mnb",` with this `"D":"mnb"`

I add a comma before `"Mapped Site"` and delete comma from the second-last row.

you can use this site [jsoneditoronline.org](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to test and show the json.

Comment: don't make people play the game of `spot the difference` ...always point out what the differences are.